# how to get fetch data from sqlite from the given string?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am creating one drop down list i want the details of  clicked name which should be fetch from database.i want to write as query in sqllite.it shouldn't  be raw query.

Below one is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", requiredColumn,"name='+idea'", null, null, null, null);
```

The variable idea is the name which i selected from the drop down list.

Any one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get details of clicked name use this query

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", requiredColumn, "name='" + idea + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Instead of

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", requiredColumn,"name='+idea'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @anamica post logcat exception.

Comment: @anamica just print "idea" value and see what's the value goin on in query.

Comment: ya am getting the value of idea bt its nt wrkng inside the query

Comment: @anamica what error you got,please post logcat exception

Comment: ya i put in log cat under my db the selected values capturing bt not wrkng in query

Comment: @anamica have you checked ooi's answer?

Comment: @anamica please post complete code, and logcat error you getting

Comment: @anamica maybe db is null, did you initialize that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(
            "contacts",
            requiredColumn, // array of column names
            name + " = ?",
            new String[] { idea },
            null, // groupBy
            null, // having
            null  // orderBy
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name= '" + idea +"'",
                null);
```

**UPDATE**
So the correct syntax for `query` is

`public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

So your code should be

```
db.query(
        "contacts",
        requiredColumn, // A list of which columns to return.
        "name = ? ", //A filter declaring which rows to return.
        new String[] { idea },
        null, 
        null, 
        null,
        null
);
```

refer [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  in android.

Try with this code, I hope this will help you.

Comment: anamica don't  want to use raw query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", new String[] {KEY_NAME}, KEY_NAME+ "=?",
            new String[] {"idea"}, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your sqlite Database  with

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private MyDBHelper dbHelper;
public void open()  
    {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

then enter your query :

```
public Cursor getData(String idea)
    {
        Cursor cursor ;

        cursor = database.query("contacts", null, 
                "name='" + idea + "'", null , null , null , null);

        if(cursor == null)
            return null ;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor ;
    }
```

Getting your data from cursor in your Activity class:

```
Cursor cursor = getData("Your_String");
String Name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
```

Hope this will works for you.

Comment: name[itemPosition]; and idea=name[itemPosition];when i try to print in logcat its worked fine bt not getting in query.

Comment: Cursor cursor = getData("Your_String"); is it in your loop? @anamica

Comment: is it possible to convert that array string to string or copy the value of array string to another array string and use in my code?

Comment: then you should write query in for loop which is on array. from that take name[itemPosition]; and send it to Cursor cursor = getData("Your_String");